# Url to image using Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, file, symfony

I am trying to download an image from a url. I want to put it in the database and save the path.

I did it for images uploaded by user but not downloaded from a URL.

All my code is below:

Controller (`$array_photo` is an array with a lot of URLs) :

```
    $file = file_get_contents($array_photos[0]);
    if ($file != NULL) {
        $fileName = md5(uniqid()) . '.' . $file->guessExtension();

        $file->move(
            $this->getParameter('image_directory'), $fileName
        );
    }


var_dump($array_photos[0]) -> string(23) "http://photos..."
```

and image_directory is a directory in web.

When I do that with a form (I use `$file = $form->get('avatarPath')->getData();` instead of 
`$file = file_get_contents($array_photos[0]);`
 that works but I get this error:

> Call to a member function guessExtension() on string

If I replace guessExtension by '.png' I get this error:

> Call to a member function move() on string

Answer (score 0):

File is indeed a string:

`$file = file_get_contents($array_photos[0]); // returns string of image data`

What you need is simply to use `file_put_contents()` :-)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

`file_put_contents($file, '/path/to/save');`

Comment: Warning: file_put_contents(http://photo...): failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections ...

Comment: i am using an api so i can't move it i have to download it, rename (that will avoid the duplicates files like this one : 0a709432efdf7f7f7f5e900bd15e20f9.png)) and after move

Comment: ?? do you have an explanation to this :)

Comment: It should be very simple, `file_get_contents()` returns a string of data. Just write that string of data into any file, create a new one! `file_put_contents($data, '/home/you/myimage.jpg')` or whatever